# I am trying to use a select drop-down to navigate to other pages in my pagination instead of the normal usage of <a>-tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

So, I have a select drop-down which is generated dynamically to be used as navigation to other pages in the script. It gets populated with the number of pages to be navigated to. If I select say "3", it loads the page to page "3" but drop-down doesn't stay selected after page load. I've tried using php 'selected="selected"' and also some local storage with javascript but I'm still not getting it right. I'm still learning my way through php and javascript.
Below are the working codes...

```
<?php
//for navigation through pages                            
if($currentpage >= 2)
                                    {
                                        echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".($currentpage - 1)."'>Previous-</a>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
     //here is the dropdown, where I have the problem of getting what is selected to stay selected after page load
                                    <select class='navno' name='navno' id='navno' onchange="pageNav(this)">
                                    <?php
                                        for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
                                        {
                                            echo "<option value='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
                                        }                                                        
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    
                                    <?php
                                    if($currentpage < $totalpages)
                                    {
                                        echo "<a class='nav_a' href='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".($currentpage + 1)."'> -Next</a>";
                                    }
?>

Then the Javascript...
<script type="text/javascript">
            //load next/previous page on the navigate select
            function pageNav(option)
            {
                location.href = option.value;
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the select block knowing what is the currentpage (and if so, make it selected).

Hence, change

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
{
echo "<option value='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
                                        }                                                        
                                        ?>
```

to

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpages; $i++)
{echo "<option ";
if ($_REQUEST["currentpage"]==$i) { echo " selected "; } 
echo " value='viewreg.php?limit=".$rowno."&currentpage=".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken Lee. Your solution works but I had to change if($_REQUEST['currentpage'] == $i) to if($currentpage == $i) as the former didn't work. Thank you once more.

Comment: Nice to know that you have solved the problem. Have a nice day and happy coding !